# Why/how to detemine when a function overwrites a local variable in Julia?

Tags: scope, julia

I am relatively new to Julia, and working on porting over some C functions to check the speed difference. One this I'm struggling with is the scope of variables. Specifically, sometimes a function call in Julia overwrites a local variable, and other times not. For example, here's a function to calculate a minimum spanning tree:

```
function mst(my_X::Array{Float64})
    n = size(my_X)[1]
    N = zeros(Int16,n,n)
    tree = []
    lv = maximum(my_X)+1
    my_X[diagind(my_X)] .=lv
    indexi = 1
    for ijk in 1:(n-1)
        tree = vcat(tree, indexi)
        m = minimum(my_X[:,tree],dims = 1)
        a = zeros(Int64, length(tree))
        print(tree)
        for k in 1:length(tree)
            a[k] = sortperm(my_X[:,tree[k]])[1,]
        end
        b = sortperm(vec(m))[1]
        indexj = tree[b]
        indexi = a[b]
        N[indexi,indexj] = 1
        N[indexj,indexi] = 1
        for j in tree
            my_X[indexi,j] = lv
            my_X[j,indexi] = lv
        end
    end
    return N
end
```

Now we can apply this to a distance matrix `X`:

```
julia> X
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0   0.54  1.08  1.12  0.95
 0.54  0.0   0.84  0.67  1.05
 1.08  0.84  0.0   0.86  1.14
 1.12  0.67  0.86  0.0   1.2
 0.95  1.05  1.14  1.2   0.0
```

But when I do so, it overwrites all of the entries of `X`

```
julia> M = mst(X)
julia> M
5×5 Array{Int16,2}:
 0  1  0  0  1
 1  0  1  1  0
 0  1  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0
 1  0  0  0  0
julia> X
5×5 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2
 2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2
 2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2
 2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2
 2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2  2.2
```

Of course I can override this if I explicitly put something like this in the function:

```
function mst(my_Z::Array{Float64})
    my_X = copy(my_Z)
     .
     .
     .
```

But it seems like the issue is deeper than this. For example, if I try to replicate this in a simple example I can't recreate the issue:

```
function add_one(my_X::Int64)
    my_X = my_X + 1
    return my_X
end
```

```
julia> Z = 1
julia> W = add_one(Z)
julia> W
2
julia> Z
1
```

What is going on here?? I've read and re-read the julia help docs on variable scopes and I cannot figure out what the distinction is.

Comment: For your `mst` function, it's pretty straightforward. You are mutating your input array in this line: `my_X[diagind(my_X)] .= lv`. In the `add_one` function you are not mutating, but _re-assigning_ a variable. _Mutation_ (`X[ind] = val`) is different from _assignment_ (`X = val`). Anyway, you cannot mutate an `Int64` since it is an immutable type.

Comment: But I guess this is exactly what needs to be explained :), i.e. mutable vs immutable types and which operations are in place and which are not. I will try to write up the summary of this in the answer.

Comment: Ah, ok. So then how can I reassign the diagonals without mutating them? And is mutation always indicated by the .=, or is the problem the indexing?

Comment: I have tried to cover your questions in my answer. If something is not clear please comment.

Comment: BTW, this is not good for performance: `tree = []`. It creates a vector of `Any`, which is _slow_. Instead do `tree = Int[]`, and then use `push!` to add elements, instead of `vcat`. Alternatively, preallocate a length `n-1` vector to hold the indices.

Comment: this is exactly what would happen in C — if you pass in an array (i.e. pointer) and mutate it within a function, you'd see the changes on the outside.  if you reassign the argument, whether it's an array or pointer or int, nothing outside the function changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are the following inter-related issues here:

1. Values in Julia can be either mutable or immutable.
2. A variable in Julia is bound to a value (which can be either immutable or mutable).
3. Some operations can modify mutable value.

So the first point is about mutability vs immutability of values. The discussion in the Julia manual is given [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Mutable-Composite-Types-1). You can check if a value is mutable or not using `isimmutable` function.

Typical cases are the following:

1. numbers, strings, `Tuple`, `NamedTuple`, `struct`s are immutable

```
julia> isimmutable(1)
true

julia> isimmutable("sdaf")
false

julia> isimmutable((1,2,3))
true
```

2. Arrays, dicts, `mutable structs` etc. (in general container types other than `Tuple`, `NamedTuple` and `struct`s) are mutable:

```
julia> isimmutable([1,2,3])
false

julia> isimmutable(Dict(1=>2))
false
```

The key difference between immutable and mutable values is that mutable values can have their contents modified. Here is a simple example:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> x[1] = 10
10

julia> x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 10
  2
  3
```

Now let us dissect what we have seen here:

- the assignment statement `x = [1, 2, 3]` binds the value (in this case a vector) to a variable `x`
- the statement `x[1] = 10` mutates the value (a vector) in place

Note that the same would fail for a `Tuple` as it is immutable:

```
julia> x = (1,2,3)
(1, 2, 3)

julia> x[1] = 10
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Tuple{Int64,Int64,Int64}, ::Int64, ::Int64)
```

Now we come to a second point - binding a value to a variable name. This is typically done using a `=` operator if on its left hand side we see a variable name like above with `x = [1,2,3]` or `x = (1,2,3)`.

Note that in particular also `+=` (and similar) are doing rebinding, e.g.:

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> y = x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> x += [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6

julia> x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6

julia> y
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

as in this case it is just a shorthand of `x = x + [1, 2, 3]`, and we know that `=` rebinds.

In particular (as @pszufe noted in the comment) if you pass a value to a function nothing is copied. What happens here is that a variable which is in the function signature is bound to the passed value (this kind of behavior is sometimes called *pass by sharing*). So you have:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> f(y) = y
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(x) === x
true
```

Essentially what happens is "as if" you have written `y = x`. The difference is that function creates a variable `y` in a new scope (scope of the function), while `y = x` would create a binding of the value that `x` is bound to to the variable `y` in the scope where statement `y = x` is present.

Now on the other hand things like `x[1] = 10` (which is essentially a `setindex!` function application) or `x .= [1,2,3]` are in-place operations (they do not rebind a value but try to mutate the container). So this works in-place (note that in the example I combine broadcasting with `+=` to make it in place):

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> y = x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> x .+= [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6

julia> y
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6
```

but if we tried to do the same with eg. an integer, which is immutable, the operation will fail:

```
julia> x = 10
10

julia> x .+= 1
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching copyto!(::Int64, ::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{0},Tuple{},typeof(+),Tuple{Int64,Int64}})
```

The same with setting index for an immutable value:

```
julia> x = 10
10

julia> x[] = 1
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::Int64, ::Int64)
```

Finally the third thing is which operations try to mutate the value in-place. We have noted already some of them (like `setindex!`: `x[10] = 10` and broadcating assignment `x .= [1,2,3]`). In general it is not always easy to decide if calling `f(x)` will mutate `x` if `f` is some general function (it may or it may not mutate `x` if `x` is mutable). Therefore in Julia there is a convention to add `!` at the end of names of functions that may mutate their arguments to visually signal this (it should be stressed that this is a convention only - in particular just adding `!` at the end of the the name of the function has no direct influence on how it works). We have already seen this with `setindex!` (for which a shorthand is `x[1] = 10` as discussed), but here is a different example:

```
julia> x = [1, 2, 3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> filter(==(1), x) # no ! so a new vector is created
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> filter!(==(1), x) # ! so x is mutated in place
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> x
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
```

If you use a function (like `setindex!`) that mutates its argument and want to avoid mutation use `copy` when passing an argument to it (or `deepcopy` if your structure is multiply nested and potentially mutation can happen on a deeper level - but this is rare).

So in our example:

```
julia> x = [1,2,3]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> y = filter!(==(1), copy(x))
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> y
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> x
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Comment: Great answer! I would maybe emphasize that `!` does not _cause_ a function to be mutating (you're not saying that, but it's easy to misread if skimming, and I've seen several people laboring under that misapprehension.)

Comment: Right - I will update the answer to make it clearer. Thank you!

Comment: To make it complete add info that Julia function arguments follow a convention named "pass-by-sharing". Hence, "values are not copied when they are passed to functions. Function arguments themselves act as new variable bindings (new locations that can refer to values), but the values they refer to are identical to the passed values. Modifications to mutable values (such as Arrays) made within a function will be visible to the caller."  Source: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/

Comment: Thanks for this. I definitely now get the difference between mutation and assignment. But I think the key sticking point is this last statement by Przemyslaw Szufel, that mutation within a function affects the variable outside the function. That 's not so clear from the definition of mutable variables, as it seems to be more about scope than about mutable variables per se, but now that I know that I can see how this is happening in my function. So is the only way to avoid this from happening in a function to use the "my_X = copy(my_Z)" approach?

Comment: You'll have to copy something anyway, either explicitly with `copy` or using some operation that copies. For example, slices copy, so if you operate on `my_Z[:]` then that will not mutate the original. A common pattern in Julia is to define a function `foo!(X)` that mutates `X`, and a super-simple companion function `foo(X) = foo!(copy(X))`. You can do that if you need both a mutating (extra fast) version, and one the doesn't mutate.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the comment what happens if you pass a value to a function (a variable name in the function signature is bound to the passed value exactly like `=` would create a binding; the difference is that function creates a new scope).